# Big O complexity of a method with a nested recursion

Tags: algorithm, loops, recursion, complexity-theory

Just trying to figure out the Big-O complexity of the following algorithm:

```
function foo1(a,b,c)
Begin
  for i:=1 to a do begin
    for j:=1 to b do begin
      if (c>1) then
        x=y+foo1(a,b,c-1);  
    end;
  end;  
End;
```

So, what do I basically think: this function has O(n^n) complexity, if a,b and c are variables. But I'm not quite sure, though.

Comment: Looks like `O((a*b)^c)` to me...

Comment: How do you get `n^n` when (1) there is no `n` in the input parameters; (2) the complexity devolves from three independent values?

Comment: Take this in steps: (1) ignore the recursion for a moment; what is the complexity of that one call to `foo1`?  (2) Replace the nested loops with a single loop that runs the same quantity of iterations.  Now, what is the complexity with the recursion in place?  (3) If you have trouble with that, try replacing the recursion with a loop that does the same thing.

Comment: I think you assume n steps for both a, b and c. Am i correct?

Comment: Yes, in this case too. But I just took the highest value, which is assumed to be n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's split the problem in parts:

1) First loop: It goes from **1** to **a**, that means that it requires **a** steps to complete the loop.

2) Second loop: It goes from **1** to **b**, that means that it requires **b** x **a** to complete those loops. Why? Because in every single loop of **a** you execute **b** loops. That means: b0 + b1 + b2 ... ba. Therefore -> a*b

3) Then you apply a recursive step. That recursion repeats in the second loop **c** times. That means that for each iteration in **b** you are going to repeat the complete process. Meaning (a * b)0 * (a * b)1 * (a * b)2 ... (a * b)c . Therefore -> O((a*b)^c)